# How do I force update the workflow.xml?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

The system doesn't update the `flow_stop` in the workflow.xml.

Try making a workflow activity:

```
<record id="act_cancelled" model="workflow.activity">
    <field name="wkf_id" ref="ig_account_voucher_wkf"/>
    <field name="name">cancelled</field>
    <field name="action">write({'state':'cancelled'})</field>
    <field name="kind">function</field>
    <field name="flow_stop">True</field>
</record>
```

And change it into this:

```
<record id="act_cancelled" model="workflow.activity">
    <field name="wkf_id" ref="ig_account_voucher_wkf"/>
    <field name="name">cancelled</field>
    <field name="action">write({'state':'cancelled'})</field>
    <field name="kind">function</field>
    <field name="flow_stop">False</field>
</record>
```

Or this:

```
<record id="act_cancelled" model="workflow.activity">
    <field name="wkf_id" ref="ig_account_voucher_wkf"/>
    <field name="name">cancelled</field>
    <field name="action">write({'state':'cancelled'})</field>
    <field name="kind">function</field>
</record>
```

The workflow always stops at the cancelled state, there is no way to update the workflow other than editing the values in the `wkf_activity` table. Is there any other way? Or this is a bug?

Comment: Have you resolved  your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Its not the bug you can change the work flow activity some thing like this

```
<record id="your_inherited_module_name.act_cancelled" model="workflow.activity">
    <field name="wkf_id" ref="your_inherited_module_name.ig_account_voucher_wkf"/>
    <field name="name">cancelled</field>
    <field name="action">write({'state':'cancelled'})</field>
    <field name="kind">function</field>
</record>
```

I hope this should helpful for you ..:)